# ymaps router или multiRouter

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В документации почти все примеры по `multiRouter.MultiRoute`.
Для того, чтобы добавлять/удалять точки простого маршрута `router.Route` пришлось изучать дебагер.

Там нашлось `route.model.getReferencePoints()` и так далее. В общем, разобраться можно, но почему этого нет в документации?

Закралась мысль, что так задумано и нужно всегда пользоваться multiRoute. Или я чего-то не понял?

---

В общем, если нужен один маршрут, можно в `multiRoute` передать

```
params: {
    results: 1
}
```

И как бы вопрос решён на этом...

Понятно, что `route` остаётся нужным для внутренней работы `multiRoute`, но наличие двух классов (`route` и `multiRoute`) немного путает вновь приобщившихся к API.

Comment: Обратная совместимость предполагает, что мы должны поддерживать то, что было давно написано. Отсюда два класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам не хватает описанной функциональности route, то нужно пользоваться multiRoute.
Также пользоваться неописанными в документации методами опасно, так как разработчики JS API Карт могут их оторвать в любой момент.

Comment: Т.е. добавление / удаление точек в router.Route не предусмотрено? Или я просто не правильно пользуюсь документацией?

Comment: Правильный путь - пользоваться multiRoute. Допустимы путь - удалять router.Route и строить новый по тем точкам, которые вы задали.